# django Templateview class instantiation

Tags: django, django-views

In the following code i am trying to call `Homeviews` class inside `HomeView` function which inturn is called by urls.py. But i do not see `get_context_data` being called. but if i separate class of `HomeViews` independently then i can see that  `get_context_data` is being called and arguments are called explicitly. From the following code how can i implement the functionality

views.py

```
   def HomeView(request):
        print "Inside def====1"
        class HomeViews(TemplateView):
            def __init__(self):
                print "Inside class====2"

            def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                print "Infunc====3"


        hv = HomeViews.as_view()
        print "After calling class"
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/someurl")
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', login_required(views.HomeView), name='home'),
```

Comment: You're not actually calling the view anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to ask why you're doing this, but to do so, pass the view into the `hv` view function you just generated.

```
def some_view(request):
    view = generic.TemplateView.as_view(template_name='foobar')
    return view(request)
```

or

```
    hv = HomeViews.as_view()
    response = hv(request)
```